# why mongorestore restore indexes?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

In document, https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/#data-exclusion,There are the following instructions:

```
mongodump output only captures the documents in the database and does not include index data. mongorestore or mongod must then rebuild the indexes after restoring data.
```

But there is the output when i run command `mongorestore --host=127.0.0.1:27018 --db=%dbname% --dir=%backup_path% --drop --objcheck --writeConcern="{w:1, wtimeout:500}" --stopOnError -vvvvv`:

```
2022-05-05T11:41:24.611+0800    restoring indexes for collection mongodb.FunctionParam from metadata
2022-05-05T11:41:24.611+0800    index: &idx.IndexDocument{Options:primitive.M{"background":true, "name":"id_1", "unique":true, "v":2}, Key:primitive.D{primitive.E{Key:"id", Value:1}}, PartialFilterExpression:primitive.D(nil)}
2022-05-05T11:41:24.612+0800            run create Index command for indexes: id_1
```

Comment: You are confused. Mongorestor restore indices whereas mongodum do not restore indices.

Comment: `mongodump` doesn't store the actual indexes, but [it does store their definition](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/blob/9f5380c0d78ba4e88ec24b6b5f8791db589d6929/mongodump/metadata_dump.go#L61), which can then be used to recreate them.

Answer (score 2):

By default mongorestore rebuild the indexes , if you want by some reason to restore only the data you may add the following option:

```
 --noIndexRestore
```

That prevents mongorestore from restoring and building indexes as specified in the corresponding mongodump output.

[official monogDB docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongorestore/#std-option-mongorestore.--noIndexRestore)